# How can I *locally* save an .html file generated by javascript (running on a *local* .html page)?

Tags: javascript, html

So I've been researching this for a couple days and haven't come up with anything conclusive. I'm trying to create a (very) rudimentary liveblogging setup because I don't want to pay for something like CoverItLive. My process is: Local HTML file > Cloud storage (Dropbox/Drive/etc) > iframe on content page. All that works, and with some CSS even looks pretty nice despite the less-than-awesome approach. But here's the thing: the liveblog itself is made up of an HTML table, and I have to manually copy/paste the code for a new row, fill in the timestamp, write the new message, and save the document (which then syncs with the cloud and shows up in the iframe). To simplify the process I've made another HTML file which I intend to run **locally** and use to add entries to the table automatically. At the moment it's just a bunch of input boxes and some javascript to automate the timestamp and write the table row from the input data.

Code, as it stands now: http://jsfiddle.net/LukeLC/999bH/

What I'm looking to do from here is find a way to somehow export the generated table data to another .html file on my hard drive. So far I've managed to get this code...

```
    if(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.innerHTML){
       var a=document.getElementById("tblive").innerHTML;
       a=a.replace(/</g,'&lt;');
       var w=window.open();
       w.document.open();
       w.document.write('<pre>&lt;tblive>\n'+a+'\n&lt;/tblive></pre>');
       w.document.close();
       }
    }
```

...to open just the generated table code in a new window, and sure, I can save the source from there, but the whole point is to eliminate steps like that from the process.

**How can I tell the page to save the generated code to a separate .html file when I click on the 'submit' button?** Again, all of this happens locally, not on a server.

I'm not very good with javascript--and maybe a different language will be necessary--but any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you could do something like this:

```
var myHTMLDoc = "<html><head><title>mydoc</title></head><body>This is a test page</body></html>";
var uri = "data:application/octet-stream;base64,"+btoa(myHTMLDoc);


document.location = uri;
```

BTW, btoa might not be cross-browser, I think modern browsers all have it, but older versions of IE don't. AFAIK base64 isn't even needed. you might be able to get away with

```
var uri = "data:application/octet-stream,"+myHTMLDoc;
```

Drawbacks with this is that you can't set the filename when it gets saved

Comment: This almost does what I want it to--I'll just have to play around with the code a bit to make sure it includes everything I need it to. I would _like_ not to have to open a new window on every submission, or have to handle the save dialog, but if those things can't be helped this is still far better than doing everything manually.

Comment: I should also mention that I figured out a way to change the save name if you create an `a` element and set its href to the data-URI, and the download attribute to the filename (sort of like how @Pogrindis did), then add it to the DOM and call `.click()` on it. (tested in FF and chrome)

Comment: Are this still works? I tested it in IE11, but it ask me what program to use to open "data". And, If I try to save it, it says unable to save.

Comment: I just tested this in Chrome and it worked perfectly. The name of the downloaded file is set to whatever the `download` attribute equals. I did not have to use base 64, but I did have to `encodeURIComponent()` in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You cant do this with javascript but you can have a HTML5 link to open save dialogue:

```
<a href="pageToDownload.html" download>Download</a>
```

You could add some smarts to automate it on the processed page after the POST.

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ghQ9M/

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, you can't.
JavaScript is restricted to perform such operations due to security reasons.

The best way to accomplish that, would be, to call a server page that would write
the new file on the server. Then from javascript perform a POST request to the
server page passing the data you want to write to the new file.

If you want the user to save the page to it's file system, this is a different 
problem and the best approach to accomplish that, would be to, notify the user/ask him
to save the page, that page could be your new window like you are doing `w.open()`.

Let me do some demonstration for you:

```
   //assuming you know jquery or are willing to use it :)
   var html = $("#tblive").html().replace(/</g, '&lt;');

   //generating your download button
   $.post('generate_page.php', { content: html })
      .done(function( data ) {
          var filename = data;

          //inject some html to allow user to navigate to the new page (example)
          $('#tblive').parent().append(
              '<a href="'+filename+'">Check your Dynamic Page!</a>');

          // you data here, is the response from the server so you can return
          // your new dynamic page file name here.
          // and maybe to some window.location="new page";  
      });
```

On the server side, something like this:

```
<?php 
   if($_REQUEST["content"]){
      $pagename = uniqid("page_", true) . '.html';
      file_put_contents($pagename, $_REQUEST["content"]);
      echo $pagename;
   }
?>
```

Some notes, I haven't tested the example, but it works in theory.
I assume that with this the effort to implement it should be minimal, assuming this solves your problem.

Comment: Javascript *in a browser* has that limitation.

Comment: This is all local, as in running right off my hard drive. I don't have any sort of server environment set up and running within Windows, either--just a plain old HTML file opened up in Firefox. I know javascript is usually restricted from exporting files this way, but I thought perhaps since the client and the server are basically one in the same in this case I might have a chance. The solution doesn't strictly have to be javascript-based, but if possible I'd like it to all function within this one local HTML file.

Comment: The limitations are imposed by your browser, and all the major browsers. As stupid as it could sound it's limited and there isn't any work around possible, unless you start dealing with elevated privileges tweaks to modify firefox user settings... But I highly discourage you to do that, been there, done that, don't do it, it's not easy or good.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the example. jQuery is fine :)
I'm not at a place where I can try it out right now, but I'll see what I can do tomorrow. Thanks again for your input!

Answer (score -1):

A server based solution:

You'll need to set up a server (or your PC) to serve your HTML page with headers that tell your browser to download the page instead of processing the HTML markup. If you want to do this on your local machine, you can use software such as [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (or MAMP for Mac or LAMP for Linux) that is basically a web server in a .exe. It's a lot of hassle but it'll work.